# ffmpeg setting not working for x264 compatibility in television

Tags: ffmpeg, mkv

I'm having some files in MKV format (x264). Some files work flawlessly in my non-smart TV, but others are not even opened at all or crashing.

I tried the following command in FFmpeg to convert it to the mp4 format since it has wide platform compatibility in TVs.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv out.mp4
```

But its still not playing in my TV, please help me with the correct ffmpeg parameters.

Comment: Your TV manual should have some specs for acceptable video (profile, level, B-frames, container..etc)

Comment: @Gyan I misplaced the manual, but I'm having some files that works flawlessly in my TV. How can I use the same settings in ffmpeg?

Comment: What's the model no.?

Comment: @Gyan Its a Sanyo TV. I searched in the web for the manual, but in vain!

Comment: Share the readout of `ffmpeg -i file` for a couple of working files.

Comment: @Gyan: Not working MKV: https://pastebin.com/Ddk72RGw Working: https://pastebin.com/bTFBTyVU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`notworking.mkv` is 10-bit H.264 (`yuv420p10le`). I'm guessing the TV can't play that. You'll have to re-encode to the more common yuv420p for the TV to be able to play it. Basic example:

```
ffmpeg -i notworking.mkv -map 0 -c copy -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p output.mkv
```